# CG float4 maths 4 times slower than float maths?

Tags: performance, opengl, shader, hlsl, cg

I wrote 20 fragment maths operations on a variable called *half H*. Then i ran 5 similar maths instructions for a *half4 XYZH*....  the second shader was very considerably slower!!! I was completely surprised, it seems more than 4 times slower!!! i am on a GTX 470. H is a procedural texture heightmap, XYZ would be the normals for each point of the texture, for lighting the texture super detailed.

Is a bunch of maths on a half4 exactly 4x slower than on a half?

this code is running alot slower than i expected, is there something i missed?

```
        half4 sel ( half s, float x){       
            if(s<=0) {half sins=tri(x*2.2); return half4(1-abs(sins),abs(sins),0,sins);} //XYZH     
            //else if(s==1){return tri(x);}
        }

        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
        {
            float3 pos = mul (_Object2World, i.uv).xyz;
            float3 posb = mul (_Object2World, i.uv).xyz;

            half4 ht = (sel(0,pos.x));
            half4 g1 =(HSVtoRGB(float3(.2+ht.w,.43*c3/2,.476322+ht.w*c1)))*(2*i.color); 
            return g1;
        }
```

Comment: nVidia GPUs since the GeForce8 series have had scalar ALUs. ATI/AMD GPUs have _always_ been scalar. When giving a scalar ALU 4 times the work, what do you expect to happen other than it taking 4 times longer?

Comment: PowerVR went scalar with Series 6 also.

Comment: I read it's more efficient to pack single floats r,g,b,a into float4 rgba, and i thought that perhaps the same maths on float4's is more efficient than on multiple discrete float's, because the pipeline can handle them in parallel, rather than sending to multple pipelines. i thought maybe it's faster at handling rgba's concurrently rather than in parallel. ok thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You arithmetic gets done four times.

Also, mixing half and float operations may delete any perf advantage you get from using half.